# Reactjs: Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null or undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, createelement

this the full error

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null or undefined. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

and this is all I have in this view

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Router, {Link, RouteHandler} from 'react-router';
import { Grid, Row, Column, List, ListItem } from '../../components/Layout';
import { RaisedButton, Paper } from 'material-ui';

const videosInformation = {
  time      : 25,
  gameId    : 15665,
  date      : '12 10 2015',
  gameName  : "Black Jack"
};

export default class Home extends Component {

  static contextTypes = {
    router  : React.PropTypes.func
  }  

  render () {
    return <Grid>                   
      <Row>
        <Column>
          <Paper>
            <List subheader="Player Info">
              <ListItem primaryText={`Name: ${videosInformation.time}`} />
              <ListItem primaryText={`Nickname: ${videosInformation.date}`} />
              <ListItem primaryText={`Age: ${videosInformation.gameId}`} />
              <ListItem primaryText={`Language: ${videosInformation.gameName}`} />
            </List>
          </Paper>
        </Column>  
        <Column>
          <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ta4xuThmAsQ" frameBorder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
        </Column>
      </Row>
    </Grid>;
  };

}
```

I am using [Material-UI](http://material-ui.com/#/components/lists)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is likely that your `Layout` file is not exporting one of the variables from this line

```
import { Grid, Row, Column, List, ListItem } from '../../components/Layout';
```

The warning would happen if one of those is undefined.

Comment: actually it was because I had  `List, ListItem` in that line you said. Just change those components and move to `material-ui` import line and that's is. I felt so stupid haha thanks

Answer (score 6):

I know the right solution has been found here but I just wanted to share another possible reason for the ReactJS `React.createElement: type should not be null or undefined` warning to trigger.

It can also happens when you have a circular dependency in your modules. Then, doing a `console.log()` of your imported module would return an empty object.

For further details, have a look at this other stackoverflow thread: [Require returns an empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875233/require-returns-an-empty-object/23875299)

Comment: Circular dependency triggered the error in my case. React's error description sucks.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone has run into this issue and the above solutions are not helping, all I had to do was move my top-level ReactDOM.render() function below the rest of the JavaScript to ensure all variables were initialized before being called. I was following the tutorial at https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial_aspnet4.html