# class export returning empty object

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have an Errors class that I'm exporting using `module.export`.

When I require the class in another file using `const Errors = require('errors.js');` and then try and use `throw Errors.NotImplimented` I get an `undefined` error at the start of `throw`.

If I try and `console.log` the Errors class after requiring it I'm shown an empty object.

```
'use strict';

class Errors {
    NotImplimented() {
        return new Error('Not implimented');
    }
    HTTP_500() {
        return new Error('500 Internal Server Error');
    }
    HTTP_404() {
        return new Error('404 Page Not Found');
    }
}

module.export = Errors;
```

Comment: You should not use a `class` for something that has no instance state. Just use a plain object literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems.  One, it's not exporting.  Try `module.exports = Errors;`

Two, you're not creating an instance of the class.  Try `const errors = new Errors();`

Additionally (not the case with this problem), you may also be getting an empty object because of a circular require, [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23875299/2415293).

Comment: Exact same thing. From what I know export is fine if you're only exporting a single var, object, etc. and you want the exported item to be the default. Since everything is inside the Errors Class that shouldn't change anything.

Comment: Calling a class like it's a function will change things.  It must be instantiated first.