# exported function unavailable when declared globally

Tags: javascript, express, require

When i load my custom made file globally, it is not loaded properly and returns an empty object:

```
const msgq = require('../db/message_queue.js');

var getList = async(url) => {
    console.log(msgq);
    ...
}
```

However, if i load locally inside the function, it works as I expected. What is the reason behind this?:

```
var getList = async(url) => {
    const msgq = require('../db/message_queue.js');  
    console.log(msgq);
    ...
}
```

Though, the weird thing is that in other parts of my code, i declared it globally and used it with no problem...

running on ExpressJS

Comment: With the first line, what happens if you run ```console.log(msgq);``` directly under the line that requires ```'../db/message_queue.js'```?

Comment: returns an emtpy object {}

Comment: Have you had a look at similar issues such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875233/require-returns-an-empty-object/23875299)?

Answer (score 0):

try let instead of const

```
    let msgq = require('../db/message_queue.js');
```